# Error with iOS icon and Phonegap Build

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

```
/tmp/gimlet/2186476/project/CNHS/Images.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[ipad][83.5x83.5][][][2x][2d][icon-83.5@2x.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has an unassigned child.
```

I am getting this error/warning when I am trying to upload pngs for an iOS icon with Phonegap Build.

This is in my config.xml:

```
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-Small-50.png"            platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-72.png"            platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-Small-50@2x.png"         platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-72@2x.png"         platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-60@2x.png"         platform="ios"        width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-76@2x.png"         platform="ios"        width="152" height="152" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-76.png"         platform="ios"        width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-60@3x.png"         platform="ios"        width="180" height="180" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png"         platform="ios"        width="167" height="167" />
```

The files are in the /www/res/icon/ios folder, and the compiler does not seen to recognize the "Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png" file.

As a result of this the iOS app has no custom icon, and has the default cordova logo.

Anyone have any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: App-83.5x83.5@2x.png - Is this file really necessary?

Comment: @LeandroPortnoy It seems like it is necessary, my Icon wouldn't display correctly any iOS device without this 83.5@2x.png being loaded correctly. I have no clue how I got it working, I guess it just randomly worked one day.